# Highslide Disable Right Click

Tags: highslide

I can't seem to get Highslide to disable right clicking on enlarged images. I have added this code one at a time to the header.php and pageTemplate.php.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       hs.blockRightClick = true;
    </script>
```

Per this site http://highslide.com/ref/hs.blockRightClick

In the Highslide code it has a statement that looks like this:

```
imageCreate : function() {
    var exp = this;

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    this.content = img;
    img.onload = function () {
        if (hs.expanders[exp.key]) exp.contentLoaded(); 
    };
    if (hs.blockRightClick) img.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; };
    img.className = 'highslide-image';
    hs.setStyles(img, {
        visibility: 'hidden',
        display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        maxWidth: '9999px',
        zIndex: 3
    });
```

What am I missing? Why is it not working? THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you're adding that blocking script *after* you load the highslide.js script. It's changing a default value, so if you call the blocking script, *then* load highslide.js, you'll be back to the default value!

Comment: Your a genius THANK YOU! I ended up putting it at the end of the page template and it worked! The key was to add it after the highslide.js loaded. Thanks again!